# mysqli_stmt_execute() does not execute the prepared query

Tags: php, mysqli

to the point.

mysqli prepared statement does not submitting data into database, and `mysqli_error` not returning any errors

might be because I made a mistake writing the error handler because it shows the message when `mysqli_stmt_execute` does not returns TRUE

**EDIT**

it looks like `mysqli_stmt_execute()` does not executes the query. why is that?

**PHP-mysqli script** :

```
// Simpan data ke dalam variable
$nama_produk=$_POST['nama_produk'];
$id_kategori=$_POST['kategori'];
$id_kategori2=$_POST['kategori2'];
$label=$_POST['label'];
$harga=$_POST['harga'];
$harga2=$_POST['harga2'];
$stok=$_POST['stok'];
$deskripsi=$_POST['deskripsi'];
$spesifikasi=$_POST['spesifikasi'];
$potongan=$_POST['potongan'];
$produk_seo      = seo_title($_POST['nama_produk']);
$tanggal=$tgl_sekarang;
$gambar=$nama_file_unik;

 $stmt=mysqli_prepare($con,"INSERT INTO produk(nama_produk,produk_seo,id_kategori,id_kategori2,label,harga,harga2,stok,spesifikasi,deskripsi,tgl_masuk,potongan,gambar) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

 mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"sssssssssssss",$nama_produk,$produk_seo,$id_kategori,$id_kategori2,$label,$harga,$harga2,$stok,$spesifikasi,$deskripsi,$tanggal,$potongan,$gambar);

 if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
    mysqli_stmt_error($stmt);
 } else {
     echo"<h1>Query gagal</h1>";
     mysqli_error($con);
     mysqli_errno($con);
     mysqli_stmt_error($stmt);
 }
```

usually there is a message saying the the number of something does match something etc but there is none of that, just a big 'Query gagal'

Comment: `seo_title()` what does that function do? and where's the form for this?  Now this `if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
    mysqli_error($con);
 }` makes no sense; you're checking if it executes but wanting to check for errors.

Comment: and where are these defined `$tgl_sekarang` - `$nama_file_unik`? Use error reporting; post your html form and the db schema for this.

Comment: `seo_title()` just a fuction to replace spaces in string into '-' for example string 'trigit or back' will become 'trigit-or-back' as for the `if(mysqli_stmt_execute)` yes I don't know the proper way to handle errors

Comment: those are defined the in php file. it is too long to write if I include the irrelevant codes too

Comment: PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php - MySQL: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.error.php

Comment: also, if the column lengths are too short, MySQL will fail silently. As will the form if it's not using a POST array but no method or GET. You also did connect successfully with `mysqli_` yes?

Comment: yes connection is ok. I also use prepared statement is much simpler form input with less variables. there are some errors appearing like the number of variable does not match or something. which is clear and I can fix it myself, but this one does not showing and error message, added that I don't know how to write error handler

Comment: I already write error_reporting(E_ALL) but the error still not showing

Comment: I don't know what it could then, sorry. Someone posted an answer below, ask them.

Comment: their answer was deleted.

Comment: I edited my question, specifically in the code `if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt))` I added `mysqli_stmt_error($stmt)`. still the errors message does not appears. please check it

Comment: wait, if I think about it, the query does not executed right?

Comment: You need to `echo mysqli_error($con);` or `echo mysqli_stmt_error($stmt);` ... the return strings so you need `echo` to get useful output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
// Simpan data ke dalam variable
$nama_produk=$_POST['nama_produk'];
$id_kategori=$_POST['kategori'];
$id_kategori2=$_POST['kategori2'];
$label=$_POST['label'];
$harga=$_POST['harga'];
$harga2=$_POST['harga2'];
$stok=$_POST['stok'];
$deskripsi=$_POST['deskripsi'];
$spesifikasi=$_POST['spesifikasi'];
$potongan=$_POST['potongan'];
$produk_seo      = seo_title($_POST['nama_produk']);
$tanggal=$tgl_sekarang;
$gambar=$nama_file_unik;

$stmt=mysqli_prepare($con,"INSERT INTO produk(nama_produk,produk_seo,id_kategori,id_kategori2,label,harga,harga2,stok,spesifikasi,deskripsi,tgl_masuk,potongan,gambar) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
if(false===$stmt){
die('Error with prepare: ') . htmlspecialchars($mysqli->error));
}

$bp = mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"sssssssssssss",$nama_produk,$produk_seo,$id_kategori,$id_kategori2,$label,$harga,$harga2,$stok,$spesifikasi,$deskripsi,$tanggal,$potongan,$gambar);
    if(false===$bp){
        die('Error with bind_param: ') . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
    }

$bp = $stmt->execute();
    if ( false===$bp ) {
        die('Error with execute: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
    }

$stmt->close();
```

Comment: hi thanks, this is really helping, the errors is finally showing itself