# Some values do not submit: two different SQL's

Tags: php

In my last question people said that I need to use prepared statements to avoid SQL injection.

I'm changing the previous SQL's now to prepared statements, as y'all wanted.

The thing is, it submits the settings, this part:

```
$stmt_setsettings = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt_setsettings, $usersettings_sql)) {
  array_push($errors, "Safe SQL failed, could not insert settings. Contact the helpdesk.");
} else {
  mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt_setsettings, "sssss", $email_show, $fname_show, $lname_show, $private_account, $profile_style);
  mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt_setsettings);
}
```

But it submits none of the actual info I need (like the username, firstname, ...)

Also, at the end of the code below it should redirect to the new profile, normally if this feels it should display "Something went wrong, refer to the helpcenter. (SE100)" but it like refreshes the sign up page and throws no error, while there is an error: the not submitting info!

I tried searching up similar questions or fixes but nothing useful found.

Can you check out the following code and let me know what is the deal with the not submitting values? Thanks!

```
  // Finally, register user if there are no errors in the form
  if (count($errors) == 0) {
    $password = md5($password_1); // Encrypt the password before saving in the database
    
    $user_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];   // Getting the IP of the user
    $bio = $config['default-bio'];   // Setting default biography
    $profileimg = $config['default-profileimg'];   // Setting default profile image
    $timestamp = date('d.m.Y');  // Defining the current date
    $activity = "on"; // Defining which state the user profile is in, online

    $userdata_sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, bio, activity, profileimg, regdate, email, password, firstname, lastname, gender, birthday, country, ip) 
                     VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        $usersettings_sql = "INSERT INTO usersettings (show_email, show_fname, show_lname, private_acc, profile_style)
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

    $stmt_signup = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt_signup, $userdata_sql)) {
      array_push($errors, "Safe SQL failed, could not sign up. Contact the helpdesk.");
    } else {
      mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt_signup, "sssssssssssss", $username, $bio, $activity, $profileimg, $regdate, $email, $password, $fname, $lname, $sex, $bday, $country, $user_ip);
      mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt_signup);
    }

    $stmt_setsettings = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt_setsettings, $usersettings_sql)) {
      array_push($errors, "Safe SQL failed, could not insert settings. Contact the helpdesk.");
    } else {
      mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt_setsettings, "sssss", $email_show, $fname_show, $lname_show, $private_account, $profile_style);
      mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt_setsettings);
    }

    session_regenerate_id();
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;

        // Generate user id
        $generateid_sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username=? ORDER BY id";
        $stmt_generateid = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
        
        if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt_generateid, $generateid_sql)) {
          array_push($errors, "Safe SQL failed, could not generate a new ID. Contact the helpdesk.");
        } else {
          mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt_generateid, "s", $username);
          mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt_generateid);

          $generateid_result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt_generateid);
        }

        while ($id = mysqli_fetch_assoc($generateid_result)) {

        if ($id['username'] <= 0) {   // Checking if the user id is a valid id (not below or equal to 0), and if not, displaying a critical error
          array_push($errors, "Something went wrong whilst signing up, please refer to the helpcenter. (SE100)");
        }
    
        if ($id['username'] > 0) {          // Redirecting the user to his or her profile if it is a valid id
          header('location: /content/users/profile?id=' . $id['username'] . '');
        }
     } 
  }
}
```

Comment: i use pdo, but isn't there a mysqli_ function to get errors from the query? I'd check that first. and make sure php errors are set to be displayed with ini_set('display_errors', true)

Comment: @Reed Errors are set to be displayed. Maybe i can use var_dump()?

Comment: It is [`mysqli_error`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) to get a string of the error from the last function `mysqli_` call. You could also use [`mysqli_report`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-driver.report-mode.php) with the STRICT flag & I think that'll make any of your mysqli_ errors throw an Exeption.

Comment: Thanks for the info! @Reed

Comment: Thanks to @Jason Aller for recently editing my question and filtering my spelling errors out. I havegot better and its a shame to read it now lol. I think lockdown is a valid excuse .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
// Finally, register user if there are no errors in the form
if (count($errors) == 0) {
    $password = md5($password_1); // Encrypt the password before saving in the database

    $user_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];   // Getting the IP of the user
    $bio = $config['default-bio'];   // Setting default biography
    $profileimg = $config['default-profileimg'];   // Setting default profile image
    $timestamp = date('d.m.Y');  // Defining the current date
    $activity = "on"; // Defening wich state the user profile is in, online

    $userdata_sql = "INSERT INTO users (`username`, `bio`, `activity`, `profileimg`, `regdate`, `email`, `password`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `gender`, `birthday`, `country`, `ip`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

    $usersettings_sql = "INSERT INTO usersettings (`show_email`, `show_fname`, `show_lname`, `private_acc`, `profile_style`)
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

    $stmt_signup = $conn->prepare($userdata_sql);
    $stmt_signup->bind_param("sssssssssssss", $username, $bio, $activity, $profileimg, $timestamp, $email, $password, $fname, $lname, $sex, $bday, $country, $user_ip);
    if(!$stmt_signup->execute()){
        array_push($errors,mysqli_error($conn));
    }

    $stmt_setsettings=$conn->prepare($usersettings_sql);
    $stmt_setsettings->bind_param("sssss", $email_show, $fname_show, $lname_show, $private_account, $profile_style);
    if(!$stmt_setsettings->execute()){
        array_push($errors,mysqli_error($conn));
    }

    session_regenerate_id();
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;

    // Generate user id
    $generateid_sql = "SELECT `id`,`username` FROM `users` WHERE `username`=? ORDER BY `id` limit 1";

    $stmt_generateid=$conn->prepare($generateid_sql);
    $stmt->generateid->bind_param("s", $username);
    if(!$stmt_generateid->execute()){
        array_push($errors,mysqli_error($conn));
    }else{    
        $generateid_result = $stmt_generateid->get_result();
    }

    $username_assoc = mysqli_fetch_assoc($generateid_result);    
    if ($username_assoc['id'] > 0) {
        // Redirecting the user to his or her profile if it is a valid id
        header('location: /content/users/profile?id=' . $username_assoc['username'] . '');
    }else{
        array_push($errors, "Something went wrong whilst signing up, please refer to the helpcenter. (SE100)");
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for this block of code, but there is a little issue. It still doesnt submit under the users table because of "column regdate cannot be NULL". Any fix?

Comment: Edit your column `regdate` and enable ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP or untick NOT NULL from the column structure.

Comment: I've updated my answer to use your variable `timestamp` as the value for `regdate` assuming your `regdate` accepts String but it is advisable to use DATETIME or TIMESTAMP

Comment: Tried to enable on update but it gives me this invalid on update clause error. Also, is it gonna save the date in the format i want? (dd.mm.yyyy)

Comment: Ok just leave it as VARCHAR and try the code I just updated.

Comment: Thanks tho! I will modify the block a bit for my understandings and i have some problems with referring to the actual profile. But the data inserts now! I might contact you here again if the referring problem does not get fixed by my knowledge. So dont close the question mods!

Comment: Alright. Don't forget to mark the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: Ofcourse i will! I never read questions with no solution that are old. I even go next level: i add all usernames that are marked as solution as note at the end of my file. Like ```// Thanks to nelsonrakson @ stackoverflow.com ``` :)

Comment: LOL... Interesting :-)

Answer (score 1):

First off, PLEASE don't ever store passwords like this:

```
$password = md5($password_1); // <-- Totally insecure
```

Instead use the built-in `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` functions. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php for a good overview of why `md5()` is not secure and examples how to handle password storage correctly.

Also, I'd recommend pulling the user out of the database and validating the password, BEFORE setting `$_SESSION['loggedin'] = true`.

Regarding your question, I'd recommend adding some additional error handling and result checking around your calls to `$conn->prepare()` and `$stmt->bind_param`. See [mysqli_stmt_execute() does not execute the prepared query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41405019/mysqli-stmt-execute-does-not-execute-the-prepared-query) for examples of how to check `$stmt->errors`.

Another general recommendation is checking `$stmt->affected_rows` to see if your insert statements are actually being executed as you expect. Your inserts should each be affecting 1 row.

Lastly, turning on the MySQL query log can be a great troubleshooting tool: [How to show the last queries executed on MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650238/how-to-show-the-last-queries-executed-on-mysql) . Are all the SQL queries in your code showing up in the log? Try running the queries manually and see if the results look right.